# How to replace composite key in select count with JPA criteria

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Found this bug in hibernate [HHH-5419](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5419)

I need to understand how I can replace Root element for type with composite key for example with asterisk.

Update hibernate, and use JPQL not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind.
Replaced query for compound key with it:

```
    CriteriaBuilder qb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = qb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<T> root = cq.from(entityClass);
    if (root.getModel().getIdType() != null)
        cq.select(qb.count(root.get("someAnotherAttribute")));
    else
        cq.select(qb.count(root));
```